A standard way to lossless store xml info as json?
I am currently working on a project that is migrating from using XML data stored in postgresql to json stored in mongodb.
The catch is: maintaining a certain degree of backward compatibility is needed, but it is not desirable to maintain the old postgresql database just for this use case.
The solution that is being discussed is storing these xml documents in json, but in a special "legacy" format that could be converted back to xml. That solution would allow us to query this legacy data using just mongo and serve the "original" documents in xml for the legacy systems that depend on this old format/data.
Most of the documents comes from legacy third-party systems and are currently being stored and served "as-is", with no modifications. The documents are grouped by schema and served thru a SOAP API. We can't store these documents in binary or textual format because the api allows some minor filtering capabilities, with a custom query syntax (that is documented for consumers) and uses the document properties for filtering. We already developed a way to convert this query syntax to mongo queries.
We initially tried xslt by creating 2 xslt files for each xml schema, one for "xml to json" and one for "json to xml", and while this solution looked solid at first glance, it became fragile when it encountered some data that did not have a strict schema.
With the appearance of multiple edge cases, instead of focusing on each schema individually, we are exploring making a "json schema" that could store all the properties a xml can, keeping information like namespaces prefixes (we have documents with multiple namespaces in the same document), attributes, children, if the xml element is self-closing or has open and close tags, etc.
So to my question: is there a standard (as in, and RFC or a commonly used schema) to losslessly convert xml to json, in such a way that it can be converted back to xml without losing information? or it is one of those cases that everyone rolls their own solution?
Thanks in advance

No, there is no standard way to store XML as JSON.  The rest of your question is more consulting engagement than SO Q/A, but here's a tip: If your XML is representing documents, you're deep in the weeds if you're trying to convert it to JSON.

It's not very common practice, to be honest, because generally people who need to support XML would just use XML-capable software rather than an XML-to-JSON translation layer. So there's no real standard, though there are a bunch of alternative conventions that people have used, most of them quite lossy. This stylesheet supports a format that includes namespaces and handles mixed content (i.e. text nodes and elements as siblings). https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/blob/master/README.md

can you not just store it as a string inside a json? its technically json, and lossless.

I'm going to post the 'stupid' answer (which will be down voted!), because that seems to work.
Xml has a standard for serialising as a string, obviously json can store strings losslessly.
here is an xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element attribute="value">             
    <childElement>        
    </childElement>             
</element>

here is a json that losslessly captures it
{
   "xml": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<element attribute=\"value\">             \r\n    <childElement>        \r\n    <\/childElement>             \r\n<\/element>"
}

The missing piece here is I suspect you need to 'query' the documents in mongo (I know nothing about this). If you know the nature of these searches, then you can extract the relevant information into another JSON field, that captures that information, and allows this search language to operate over the metadata/summary json data, but extract the data from the raw string for serving the actual XML, then that seems feasible. If the nature of these queries is open ended then I think you're in trouble, even if you do have a lossless 1:1 mechanism, you then need to query over it, at best that sounds hard.

I don't think this is helpful. The question is clearly about moving data (information) from one container to another. Wrapping one container in another does not accomplish anything useful.

so you move the xml into the json by embedding it as a string in json

I have actually done something very very similar to this in real, life creating a complex schema, and then realising that storing it simlpy as a 'document' with 'key' searchable values was much much easier

Treating the original XML simply as "payload", and extracting fragments of it into JSON format to serve as an index is a perfectly valid technique to avoid having to round-trip from XML to JSON back to XML, and to simplify the JSON data structure used by the search API.

Yes I already did. I don't think it's a bad idea (at all!) to use a fully-generic transformation to convert XML into JSON; that makes it possible to query any XML without restriction (including e.g. with namespaces and mixed content), but there's no actual need to define the inverse transformation, and round-trip the JSON back to XML, if the original XML is saved in the Mongo DB as a JSON string which can be returned to the client, as is.

given an XPath query (as a specification of something you may want to do, but optimised to XML), you would though have to apply the inverse transformation to it somehow to get the equivalent query in your mongo infrastructure, in general I think that would be hard and possibly quite ugly to use....of course....it may not be....but thats my instinct.
